# Free/Libre open source Q&A site software, Stack Exchange replacement

Tags: open-source, web-apps

Stack Exchange has great features, but does not empower groups of people to set up and host their own Q&A site, quickly or privately.

What other web-based Q&A software options exist that might compete with Stack Exchange, specifically by being free and open source?

Comment: Do you want self-hosted alternatives?

Comment: Yes, self-hosted is what I'm most interested in.

Comment: Although most of us know Stack Exchange ;), you should still list which features you need (you likely don’t need a 100% clone, do you?). See [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/60). There are many "clones", see [Stack Exchange clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/193139).

Comment: Note that I got initial quotes for SE implementation at my work (I run large internal systems group) and I was quoted in the deep 6 figures.  Basically we could pay that much but it would take a complete buy-in from several sectors and tons of CHANGE.  It is too bad they don't off a more tiered rollout to get companies going.  I know at my company we can't get people to quit making docs, let alone post everything in Q&A... so I can see the need for opensource.  SE really doesn't have a good internal business model.

Comment: // , There are other reasons than the expense to consider alternatives to SE, too. For example, SE entails some serious implicit risks.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/stackoverflow/?license=opensource&platform=self-hosted

Answer (score 4):

[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io) is new (year 2018) open source Q&A software, inspired by StackOverflow, and forum software like Discourse.

In addition to Q&A topics and categories, you can have open-ended discussions, and Slack like chat channels. So people  can go to your place, not just for Q&A, but also for talking and being social. You can have private staff categories & chat.

Here's an example discussion — copied from StackExchange/StackOverflow: (cc-by-sa license)
https://insightful.demo.talkyard.io/-7/how-do-i-get-myself-out-of-bed-in-the-morning

Talkyard is beta software currently (May 2018) and I'm developing it. [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard), and [SaaS hosting here](https://www.talkyard.io/pricing). Screenshot:

[image: Answers to how-to-wake-up-on-time]

<sub>(The posts are from [this StackExchange question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/2), license: [cc-by-sa-3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/))</sub>

Comment: Talkyard seems to be a nice approach, however it seems that one of the core features of stackexchange i.e. the vote and reputation system is missing right now.

Comment: @student — yes the reputation system is missing. It's a pretty popular feature request, and I'm thinking about implementing it the nearest weeks / months.

Comment: @student — Votes: Hmm, there're Like votes that work fairly much like StackOverflow upvotes, but are displayed differently, and currently not directly visible on the question list page. I think it'd be nice with config options so one could choose to make the Like vote, and a Disagree vote Talkyard has,  behave / look-like StackOverflow's votes.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some free/open-source self hosted alternatives to Stack Exchange,

## **[LampCMS](http://www.lampcms.com/)**

> LampCMS is an full-featured Open Source Question and Answers web program written in PHP with deep integration with Facebook, Twitter, Google, Linked-IN, Tumblr and Blogger APIs. It uses MongoDB as a database to achieve speed and scalability.
>
> [image: LampCMS User Interface]

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: https://www.opensourcecms.com/lampcms/ @Julia

Answer (score 3):

You can try Wordpress together with the [DW Question & Answer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-question-answer/) plugin.

The plugin builds a complete Q&A system for your WordPress site, like Quora or Stackoverflow. It supports multi-languages, shortcodes, reCAPTCHA, email notification system and so on.

User interface screen shot:

[image: DW Question & Answer User Interface]

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is Askbot, built on Django (Python). The source is located here:

https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel

From the Readme:

> Commercial hosting of Askbot and support are available at https://askbot.com

And the license section:

> Askbot software is licensed under GPL, version 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [TopAnswers](https://github.com/topanswers/topanswers)

> TopAnswers is what Stack Overflow should be: focused on communities and knowledge sharing, not profit. We share some of the same aims:
>
> - Focus on questions and answers. Everything else we do is to help us produce useful questions and answers.
> - Keep the signal:noise ratio high with a voting system that helps good answers float to the top.
> - Build communities of experts across a diverse range of subjects.

Answer (score 0):

## **[OSQA](https://github.com/dzone/osqa)**

> OSQA is a free, entry-level Q&A system from the makers of AnswerHub, the market-leading professional Q&A platform. OSQA is a great solution for smaller sites with limited needs.
>
> [image: OSQA User Interface]

Comment: The project doesn't seem to be active anymore.

Comment: @student Link updated, that's unfortunate though