# Where is the ask system source code?

Tags: open-source

When I surf the Internet, I found the [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/92340/is-there-any-add-apt-repository-similar-type-command-to-add-repository/), and the [ask.openstack.org](https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/), the ask system seems same source, they must be one source code.

So, does the source code is open source?

Comment: Please see https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/820/140

Comment: I should have explained better, there are too problems with this question: 1) Software identification is off-topic, see link above, which means that your only option is to change that question into something like "Is there an open source Q&A engine?" 2) That question happens to have been asked already. If you believe your question is different, please make it on-topic and include more requirements, then we will be happy to reopen it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of both sites it says ‘powered by Askbot’.

And ask.openstack.org also links to the source: https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel

From the Readme:

> Commercial hosting of Askbot and support are available at https://askbot.com

And the license section:

> Askbot software is licensed under GPL, version 3.

Comment: The ASKBOT is hosted commercially, why they put their code on github?

Comment: @aircraft My guess is that Askbot leverages the open source community to keep improving their product. At the same time, they offer hosting for those who do not have dedicated resources for running a Q and A site. Also, it is a way for those who *do* host it themselves, to get their own patches into the project.

Comment: Great answer, could you please post it at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18406/free-libre-open-source-qa-site-software-stack-exchange-replacement ? Thanks and sorry for the trouble! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is powered by Askbot.

Take a look at https://askbot.com/

Here is the pricelist: https://askbot.com/plans/ > not open source.

Comment: https://askbot.com/contribute/ 
Askbot is a free open source Question and Answer (Q&A) forum software written in Django and Python.

This was taken by their website. I am little confused about your answer?

Comment: @Sonamor The software is free, but the hosting offered on this website is not.